# How can I make a public HTML folder in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, public-html

Simple question, but for some reason I couldn't find the exact answer on Google:

I have a fresh Ubuntu install on Slicehost, and would like to make a public directory in my home dir for a simple website containing a bunch of static HTML files. How do I do this? Is it just a matter of typing `mkdir public_html` and setting the permissions, or is there a cleaner way? (I remember in the past I've had issues where every time I copied a file into my public_html directory, I would have to manually set its permissions, which was quite frustrating.)

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions below and everything worked. Thanks everyone. Sorry if the question is off-topic. You can close this question if you wish.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Assuming you've already installed apache, do the following:

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
sudo service apache2 reload
```

The first command enables the userdir apache mod, which does exactly what you want.  The second reloads apache configurations so that it starts using the new configuration.

To install apache2:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Of course, you'll also need to make sure that the permissions on your public_html folder allow the www-data user to see the files in there -- 755 usually works well. To do this:

```
mkdir ~/public_html
chmod -R 755 ~/public_html
```

This will recursively (-R) go through your public_html and set the permissions to 755 (owner rwx, and both group and other r-x, r-x).

Comment: but where shall I put public_html folder? under /var/www/ ?

Comment: Put the public_html file in the user's home directory as shown above `mkdir ~/public_html`.

Comment: when I tried for $sudo a2enmod userid ,, it is giving me an error Module userid doesn't exit! ,, but I have created it in my home directory . how to resolve it?

Answer (score 11):

The other answers are on the right track with `mod_userdir`, but using that will give your website the base URL `http://www.yourdomain.com/~username/` - for instance, a file `/home/username/public_html/index.html` would be accessible as `http://www.yourdomain.com/~username/index.html`.  If you want your files to be accessible under the domain root, as `http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html` for example, then you'll need to put the directive

```
DocumentRoot /home/username/public_html
```

in the Apache configuration file.

Comment: what if I want to put the files under /var/www/public_html?

Comment: Just use that as the document root instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_userdir.html) for Apache, otherwise you need to set up symlinks from `/var/www/` or wherever.

Your permissions issue is because Apache does not have read access to your files.  You need to allow read access to `www-data` (or whatever the user is; distro-specific).