# best way to develop and manage websites locally in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, web, lamp

I'm new in Ubuntu, I use Ubuntu 12.04,

I want to develop websites locally, so I installed LAMP, and I found that my www folder is in '/var/www/' so when I try to add new project in it using Netbeans or modify files or what so ever, I face permission problem !!

I would like to know the best way I could use to manage and develop websites with ease?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way might be to add user directories for your web server. This way you can have a `~public_html` folder which holds your html pages and `http://localhost/~<username>/` accesses it.

If you want to deploy your apps to /var/www you can make yourself a member of www-data:
$ `sudo adduser <username> www-data`

Comment: I didn't get your first answer, for the second, it might be like this: usermod -a -G www-data <username>  but it didn't work for me, I still can't manage the /var/www
thanks anyway

Comment: For the first suggestion, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526742/how-can-i-make-a-public-html-folder-in-ubuntu. For the second suggestion, you need to logout and back in so the user gets the new group.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found is to create my own **public_html** folder under my personal home space by following this tutorial: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-ubuntu.html#createDocumentRootLocation

Read the "Specifying the Document Root for the Apache2 HTTP Server" section,

The basic idea is to redirect the DocumentRoot to the new **public_html** folder you create, and that's it.

I hope it helps.